# Android CMAKE linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

My CMAKE Android NDK always failed when linking the library. In My .c code, the library always `error: undefined reference to FUNCTION_NAME`. This is my CMake Code:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.1)
project("app")

add_library(
        abc

        SHARED

        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/abc.c)
add_library(
        libA

        SHARED

        IMPORTED )

# App
add_library(
        custom-native

        SHARED

        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/app.cpp)

set_target_properties(libA PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libA.a)

# Log
find_library(
        log-lib

        log)

target_link_libraries(abc
        PUBLIC libA)
```

And also shows `error: linker command failed with exit code 1`. I already try to solve this in 2 days. I don't have a clue. If you guys know how to fix this, please let me know.
This is my gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 54
    versionName "1.0.54"
    multiDexEnabled true
    signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags ''
        }
    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
        version '3.18.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely, the problem is about your **C/C++ code**. You need to include that code into the question post (in form of [mcve]). Also, you need to provide **exact error message** you got. That message should include information about which exact source (or object) file causes it.